# find('order-button', :disabled => false) raises ArgumentError: invalid keys

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

on the website that I am testing, the following happens:

- you click a button
- an ajax-call is executed, all input fields are temporarily disabled
- once the data is retrieved, the fields are filled in and no longer disabled

To wait for this to happen (no sleep or other stupid solutions), I was thinking about something like this:

```
find('order-button', :disabled => false).click
```

But I get the following Exception: `ArgumentError: invalid keys :disabled, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait`

How do I get this to work? I am using the latest version of Capybara (2.1.0)

Any input in this is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:disabled` option [is supported only by following selector types](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/9f516cfd7ae049aa0c0e2706c4eb66031708c8e0):

```
:field
:link_or_button
:button
:fillable_field
:radio_button
:checkbox
:select
:file_field
```

It can be used as:

```
find(:field, 'field_id', disabled: false)
```

This option is not supported by `:css` that you seem to use.

With `:css` you are expected to use css's attributes which is much shorter:

```
find('#field_id:not([disabled])')
```

Comment: I used `find(:field, 'field_id', disabled: false)` and it worked like a charm. Thank you, @Andrey